# Windows 10 get UAP version

Tags: windows-10

How do I get programatically current Windows 10 UAP version?

I did not find any suitable class or method.

GetVersionEx does not seem to be supported.

Comment: Can you explain what you want the version number for?

Comment: For internal metrics.

Answer (score 1):

For things like metrics and analytics, you can use the new [`AnalyticsInfo` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.aspx). The version number you get is a string-ized representation of the four-part version number (major.minor.revision.build).